# Using AngularJS code in template property of kendo window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using kendo window with AngularJS in the following way.

**HTML Code**

```
    <div kendo-window="showProspectDetailWindow" k-title="'Prospect Detail window'"
     k-width="" k-height="" k-visible="false"
     k-content="{template:confirmationWindowTemplate}"
     k-on-open="" k-on-close=""></div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
$scope.confirmationWindowTemplate = 'Are you sure you want to delete?<br />This data  will not be recoverable, do you want to continue ?<br /><div class="pull-right"><button class="k-primary" ng-click = "yesButton()">Yes</button><button class="k-button" ng-click="noButton()"> No</button></div>';
```

I have created a model in the script in the following way

```
 $scope.createProspectDetailModel = function(data)
 {               
            $scope.prospectDetail.AccountId = data.AccountId;
            $scope.prospectDetail.BusinessType = data.BusinessType;
            $scope.prospectDetail.FirstName= data.FirstName;
 }
```

The above code works. With the help of debugger I can verify that the values from the data field are going into each of the $scope.prospectDetail value. However, when I change my template into

```
$scope.confirmationWindowTemplate = 'Are you sure you want to delete {{prospectdetail.FirstName}}'
```

It doesn't work. I also tried

```
$scope.confirmationWindowTemplate = 'Are you sure you want to delete {{#= prospectdetail.FirstName #}}'
```

but it doesn't work as well. I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288918/is-it-possible-to-pass-static-html-markup-content-to-kendo-angular-modal-window) link on SO but didn't help. I have searched a lot but still cannot find the solution to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the answer myself. I changed the **HTML Code** . Removed the **k-content**

```
<div kendo-window="confirmationWindow" k-title="'Confirmation window'"
  k-width="" k-height="" k-visible="false"
  k-on-open="" k-on-close=""></div>
```

and assigned it in the script

```
$scope.confirmationWindow.content('Are you sure you want to delete'+ $scope.prospectDetail.FirstName '?<br />
```

Comment: myKendoModal.content('blah blah') has no effect for me.
Both if I call "content" function before or after "open()".